# What is a good way to implement a "delayed" list stream in Scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz-stream

I tried doing this, but that did not work:

```
Process("Hello", "Salut", "Bye", "Ciao").interleave(time.sleep(0.5.seconds).repeat)
```

Comment: @user2864740 It means that when adding a `Sink` (in my case standard output) to the `Process`, nothing is being sent to it. I was trying to keep the question succinct for people familiar with scalaz-stream. Do you suggest I update the question to provide more detail?

Comment: Yes - at least an explanation of the observed behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Process("Hello", "Salut", "Bye", "Ciao") zip (time.awakeEvery(0.5 s))
.map(_._1)

Comment: Cool! Yes that does appear to work. Any idea why the above does not?

Comment: Actually I think the reason why this doesn't work is that you interleaving the stream , whereas in my solution you zipping the stream. I think it would be obvious when you look on definition of ZIP and INTERLEAVE.